# What does 50A on a +12V rail mean?

Tags: power-supply

What I'm wanting to know is what does 50A on the +12V rail mean? Does it by chance have to do with the total output it can supply to the PC?

Comment: That means your PSU can output up to 50 A on the +12V rail.

Comment: @gronostaj speaking of, what is a rail specific to PSUs?

Comment: This article by Gabriel Torres is pretty good at explaining the PSU: http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-power-supplies/

Comment: Some PSU's have more than one rail, this means it is a separate 12v power circuit (rail). If you have a PSU with 2 12v rails and each does 50 [amps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp), then you have a total of 100amps you can connect 12 volt devices to.  Better explained here...http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/power-supply-specifications-atx-reference,3061-2.html